# php curl upload to megaupload

Tags: php, curl, upload, megaupload

I create a php script to upload a file to megaupload on my account but I have some problem on the upload part.
I'm using Curl with php.

I set the following options:

```
CURLOPT_POST => 1
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"
CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10

CURLOPT_COOKIE => session_name() . '=' . session_id()
CURLOPT_COOKIE => realpath($cookie)
CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => realpath($cookie)
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => realpath($cookie)
```

I send a first post to connect to my acount.
This part seem to work, when I check the acount page I get my info.

Then I try to send a file with the multiupload form

```
    $multi = $this->getPage("/multiupload/index.php");
    preg_match('#http://[w]{3}[0-9]#', $multi, $match);

    $startPos = strpos($multi, $match[0]);
    $endPos = strpos($multi, "\"", $startPos);
    $link = substr($multi, $startPos, $endPos - $startPos);
    echo "Link = " . $link . "\n";

    $startPos = strpos($link, "UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER=") + 18;
    $endPos = strlen($link);
    $id = substr($link, $startPos, $endPos - $startPos);
    echo "id = " . $id . "\n";

    $this->setPost(array ("sessionid" => "" . $id . "",
                            "UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER" => "" . $id . "",
                            "file" => "@" . realpath($fileName),
                            "message" => "abc",
                            "toemail" => "",
                            "fromemail" => "",
                            "password" => "",
                            "trafficurl" => "",
                            "multiemail" => ""));
    $page =  $this->getPage($link, 1);
```

But I receive a "Empty reply" answer

I can't figure out why my request is wrong.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

upload here

```
http://www1016.megaupload.com/upload_done.php?UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER=01310301330397063843100367215169&user=[USER]&s=[SIZE]
```

make sure you are passing all the necessary postfields